# Know user's twitter applications installed

Tags: api, twitter, twitter4j

first of all, I'm spanish so sorry about my English.
It's my first question, so I hope do it correctly.
I have been looking for in the searcher and google but I didn't find solution about my problem.
I need to know who of my friends have installed one app via API (I have twitter4j lib.).
I have a friend's list id and I need to know if one per one have or not permission to one app.
I have seen all the methods in twitter4j but I don't know how do it.
It seems easy... so sorry if the answer is stupid, I have tried to search everywhere I have could.

Thanks,

Comment: You want to know the applications a user has signed into?

Comment: Not exactly, I want to know if a user have one specifically application or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible via twitters [**settings**](http://twitter.com/settings/applications) page, however there's no API available for this.

If you mean `source of the tweets`? Like `Web`, `Mobile Web`, `Twitter for Blackberry`

Source of tweets (Application user tweeted with) is returned for each tweet gotten.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/show/%3Aid

Comment: The application don't tweet anything.
I have an application that get friend's ids for the authenticating user.

Comment: The application don't tweet anything.
I have an application that first of all get friend's ids for the authenticating user.
With this friend's ids I need to make an if about if this friend have or not installed the application named "Example" because I only want get the profile about friends that have installed the application named "Example".
Thanks.

Comment: Ok. I get it. Its not possible to do that from the API. You can check here http://twitter.com/settings/applications for yours.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Not all can be easy. I will think another way to do it.
It's a final project of the career so it's not possible say "the API don't allow this".
It's strange that I can get, update, delete... profile, list, followers,...but not the applications of the user.
Thanks for answer so fast, this page is very useful for beginner people like me